# Receiving a #[object%20Object] in my html webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I a doing a webpage with a template but when i do scroll i receive a url with #[object%20Object].

When I press the li element, the page scrolls to the services section as expected however, the url is appended with /#[object Object] instead of /inscripcion.

This is code in index.html:

```html
<ul class="nav">
   <li class="scroll-to-section"><a href="#inscripcion">Inscripciones</a></li>
   <li class="scroll-to-section"><a href="#recorridos">Recorridos</a></li>
   <li class="scroll-to-section"><a href="#schedule">Reglamento</a></li>
   <li class="scroll-to-section"><a href="#contact">Contacto</a></li> 
   <li class="scroll-to-section"></li> 
</ul>        
<!-- ***** Code to scroll ***** -->
<section class="section" id="inscripcion">
```

And this is code un custom.js:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        
        //smoothscroll
        $('.scroll-to-section a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(document).off("scroll");
            
            $('a').each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            })
            $(this).addClass('active');
          
            var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
            var target = $(this.hash);
            console.log(target);
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: (target.offset().top) + 1
            }, 500, 'swing', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
                console.log(window.location.hash);
                $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
            });
        });
    });

    function onScroll(event){
        var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
        $('.nav a').each(function () {
            var currLink = $(this);
            var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
            if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
                $('.nav ul li a').removeClass("active");
                currLink.addClass("active");
            }
            else{
                currLink.removeClass("active");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: you first declared `var target = this.hash` in vanilla, and then `var target = $(this.hash)` in jQuery. Use different variables, like `var hash = this.hash` and `var target = $(this.hash)` to distinguish the string value from the html element object, so that you can then write: `window.location.hash = hash`